# VB .net, how do I make a String recognised as code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am making a program that has an Array full of images that all load in at the start.
To do this i have been using this code...

```
    Image(1) = My.Resources._0
    Image(2) = My.Resources._5
    Image(3) = My.Resources._10
    Image(4) = My.Resources._15
    Image(5) = My.Resources._20
```

and so on right up to Image(72). But i want to now make it up to 360, and would rather have it automatically fill in for me... So the manual code is...

```
    Image(1) = My.Resources._1
    Image(2) = My.Resources._2
    Image(3) = My.Resources._3
```

and so on up to...

```
    Image(360) = My.Resources._360
```

But that would take a while and isn't very compact and easy to change... So i want it to have a repeat... So far I have this...

```
    Dim Count2 As Integer = 1
    Dim Resource As String

    Do Until Count2 = 361
        Resource = ("My.Resources._" + Text(Count2))
        Image(Count2) = Resource
        Count2 = Count2 + 1
    Loop
```

So my only problem with this code is that is doesn't recognise the "Resource" variable as code... So...

```
    Dim Resource As String

    Resource = ("My.Resources._" + Text(1))
    Image = Resource
```

Does not see Resource as

```
    My.Resources._1
```

It sees Resource as

```
    "My.Resources._1"
```

Comment: That's not vba but vb.net.

Comment: @KostasK. Ops, Fixed now :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ My.Resources. is code that tells the program to look into it's saved resources and then _0, is a file in resources    ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to loop through it like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 360
    Image(i) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + i.ToString)
Next i
```

Comment: @PEH I have a 2nd Q... It's that code that u just gave me... i have it doing this picMyShip.Image = Image(CurrentImage) every 16ms on a timer... And when the image gets between 62 and 72 it crashes

Comment: @Fercorn Please ask a new question for that and include a proper example [mcve] and a good description of what went wrong. We cannot answer new questions in comments.

Comment: @PEH I have :).

Comment: @PEH https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500881/unhandled-exception-when-loading-images-automatically