# Unhandled exception when loading images automatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Simply, this code...

```
    Dim Count2 As Integer = 1
    Dim ImageCount As Integer = 0

    For Count2 = 1 To 72
        Image(Count2) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + ImageCount.ToString)
        ImageCount = ImageCount + 5
    Next Count2
```

Loads up all my images in the Array...
and this...

```
    picMyShip.Image = Image(CurrentImage)
```

Puts images onto my picture box (runs every 16ms, i change it by pressing keys)... But for some reason, when CurrentImage = 62 to 72 the code,

```
    picMyShip.Image = Image(CurrentImage)
```

Will come up with an error,

```
    "System.ArgumentException was unhandled"
```

What have i done wrong?
I am new to this so please specify certain things I should change about my question.
If this helps, here's the program itself...

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19SROjGehvt9YYIRdYQkH8LmGsCnpRkS-?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't use invalid tags when making questions.  If you knew it's `vb.net` you're working in, why tag `vba`, `vbscript`, and `vb6`?

Comment: Just a little tip: If working with very short intervals (such as _16ms_ as you stated), you should pause the timer whilst you are executing code in the interval.  You may be getting another interval before your first one has finished.

Comment: @Martin :O. How do I do that?

Comment: @Martin... That was set because I did that on my previous question and forgot to change it on this one... And when i did the previous one i thought they where all the same :/.

Comment: No problem, was just an observation.  I've added an answer that shows how to pause the `Timer` during the `Tick` event execution

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what is being returned by `Image(CurrentImage)` in the case of items 62-72?  The error seems to be related to the image dimensions, although I can't see why that would be without knowing more about the resources themselves

Comment: @Martin    ???    62 or 72? Because they are the only ones that can seeing it crashes when it reaches either os it cant get to any numbers inbetween? The resources and in the resources file (unique name i used) in my program (Link above ^^^)

Comment: It is not necessary to declare 'Count2`. This happens automatically in the `For` loop. Can we see the declare for the `Image` array. Choosing a property name for a variable is not a great idea. Are you sure there are enough images in resources to fill the array? Are all the images the same file type when they were originally placed in resources?

Comment: @Mary :O, yeah... :D ... I thought I had to declare it as a variable :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. Because all my images where 1.5mb, it was trying to store to much into the one array and didn't store the last 10 images therefor when it tried to load those images there was nothing to load

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @XingyuZhao I tried to when i posted the answer but it wouldn't let me

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, this could be due to the fact that the next interval (`Tick`) is occuring on your timer before your code has finished from the first.

With a short duration of 16ms (as you indicated), it makes sense to pause the timer whilst you are executing the `Tick` code.  You could do this very simply like this:

```
Private Sub tmrTicker_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTicker.Tick
    ' Stop timer during code
    tmrTimer.Enabled = False

    ...

    ' Restart timer now code has finished
    tmrTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

When the `Tick` event fires, the timer is immediately stopped (`tmrTimer.Enabled = False`).  Then, before the event handler finished, the timer is re-enabled (`tmrTimer.Enabled = True`).

This will ensure that your code finishes before the next `Tick` event can occur.

Note: This will have the side effect of delaying the time between the `Tick` events.  If your interval is 16ms, then this will be delayed by *the length of time it takes to execute the code in your `Tick` event handler*.

Note 2: If you are building a precisely timed code then your solution using the Windows Forms Timer control is not the right one.  It is well known for being relatively imprecise.

Comment: D: ... I'm keeping that code in my program because then it wont run too early... But it didn't fix my problem, or change it D: .... Thanks anyway